# One-To-Many travel time calculation and export

Tags: one-to-many, export-to-excel, google-distancematrix-api

I have an excel document with every Australian postcode including LONG and LAT coordinates for each.

What I need to be able to do is get the travel time from one location in Aus to each of the locations in this excel document and end up with these times exported into my original document. I'm happy to do this manually with a separate export and using some excel formulas to match the data.

Does anyone know of any tools/websites that can do this? I know there are some websites offering API to do a one-to-many matrix but unless you're only doing a few locations it would be incredibly tedious and time consuming to modify the API call to do about 1000 locations.

I am also not really good with API calls so would need some good documentation to assist if this was the path I had to take.

Appreciate any help or resources people can direct me to.

[image]